# RecordType name in IF

Tags: apex, trigger, record-type

I am struggling with how to select record type in Apex. 
I have been given some examples, but I still don't get it - sorry if it already has been answered somewhere - I am very new to this, so I guess I'll ask for explicit solution on my simplified code...

In the following example, the code never puts 'A' in RT__c field (always 'other'). There are 2 record types 'A' and 'B' (names & developer names are the same). Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
trigger recordTypeTest on Contact (before insert, before update) {
    for(Contact con : trigger.new){
        if(con.recordType.Name ==  'A' )  {con.RT__c = 'A';}
        else                              {con.RT__c = 'other';}
  }
}
```

Different try (using some advice) - doesn't work...

```
trigger recordTypeTest on Contact (before insert, before update) {
    Map<Id, RecordTypeInfo> recordTypes = Contact.SObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosById();
    String RTName;

    for(Contact con : trigger.new){
        RTName= recordTypes.get(con.RecordTypeId).getRecordTypeName();
        if(RTName == 'A')     {con.RT__c = 'A';}
        else                  {con.RT__c = 'other';}
  }
}
```

Comment: Your first try unambiguously will not work. Can you describe what behavior or error you observed on your second try?

Comment: Further, this appears to me to be a need that can easily be met with a formula field - no Apex required..

Comment: I agree with @DavidReed, this seems to me a Formula Field candidate. Please put more details so that we can guide you to correct solutions

Comment: Yes, this can be formula, but I have simplified the real case.
I'd like to see how I should write it in general (best on this example so I could really get it). 

2nd try - I couldn't save it because I took it from some more complex example I guess....     

Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void getRecordTypeName() from the type Schema.RecordTypeInfo at line 7 column 51

Comment: More details... It is just an example, but what I'm trying to comprehend is "How to run pieces of code based on RecordTypeName" the easiest way. That is why I've come up with this example which I understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second approach is probably the best way. The error your are seeing

> Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void
>   getRecordTypeName() from the type Schema.RecordTypeInfo at line 7
>   column 51

Is because the method does not exist. The [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_RecordTypeInfo.htm) show that the correct method name is `getName()`

So try:

```
trigger recordTypeTest on Contact (before insert, before update) {
    Map<Id, RecordTypeInfo> recordTypes = Contact.SObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosById();
    String RTName;

    for(Contact con : trigger.new){
        RTName= recordTypes.get(con.RecordTypeId).getName();
        if(RTName == 'A')     {con.RT__c = 'A';}
        else                  {con.RT__c = 'other';}
  }
}
```

Comment: I would like to advice that is better to use getDeveloperName() instead of getName().

Comment: I agree @mPeixoto